# Scrollview inside pivot item doesn't full scroll

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, scrollviewer, pivotitem

Hello I have this Page XAML. The problem its that the text inside each PivotItem doesn't scroll correctly, just scroll a bit but no to the end. Pivot works correctly, you can flip Items Horizontally. How can i achieve the correct behavior on the scrolls?

```
<StackPanel>
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,12,0">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                               Foreground="#5D5B5D" 
                               FontWeight="Light" 
                               TextAlignment="Justify" 
                               Margin="0,0,12,0" 
                               Padding="0,0,4,0" 
                               Text="Change for this a very large text so it can scroll!!! "></TextBlock>
                <Button Content="OK"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            Margin="0,18" 
                            Padding="42,4"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,12,0">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                               Foreground="#5D5B5D" 
                               FontWeight="Light" 
                               TextAlignment="Justify" 
                               Margin="0,0,12,0" 
                               Padding="0,0,4,0" 
                               Text="Change for this a very large text so it can scroll!!! "></TextBlock>
                <Button Content="OK"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            Margin="0,18" 
                            Padding="42,4"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code I saw that you use a `StackPanel` outside of the `Pivot` control, and you didn't set the `orientation` property, so by default the `StackPanel` stacks items vertically from top to bottom in the order they are declared. This will influence the Vertical-scroll-mode `ScrollViewer` inside of it.

A `ScrollViewer` works when its content's size bigger than the `ScrollViewer`'s size, when a `ScrollViewer` is inside of a `StackPanel`, it has no limit of size, the size will fit the child inside of it, so can't a `ScrollViewer` work correctly.

In this case, you can change the `StackPanel` outside of your `Pivot` to `Grid`, it will solve the problem, or you can give your `ScrollViewer`s a limit height like `<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" Height="300">`, this can also solve the problem.

Comment: I've used a parent grid instead stack panel as you suggested. Now the Scrollviewer works as i expected, thanks. I used grid's rows to nest/stack a pivot and others views needed.